# How to turn on or off Grafana alert indicators on panel?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, graph-visualization

I realize that on some of my Grafana panels, I can't see vertical lines indicating the start and end of alerts. Some of my panels are working fine, I can see alert indicators (see screenshot). The question is how to turn on and off these indicators? I can't find anything on the internet or in documentation.

Alert indicators

[image: Alert lines]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of all the problems was this small annotation that was missing. I added it and now vertical lines appear.

[image]